# Iterator expects instance of Object outside of the class which implements it

Tags: java, generics, iterator, doubly-linked-list, iterable

couldn't help but feel the title is kinda vague, sorry about that. I couldn't describe it better.

I'll get a little more into detail; I'm trying to figure out how to get an iterator working the way I want it to outside of the class it's implemented in. I couldn't manage to find any information on my problem. This is part of an assignment for University, AlphaTest.java should be left as is.

I have a class, Alpha, which holds a class which follows the doubly linked list principle, Bravo. Bravo holds the link to the previous and next instance in the list.

I want to be able to iterate through the linked list with an iterator implemented in the Alpha class so that I can easily go through each instance using a for loop like this:
`for(Bravo b: alphaInstance) {...}`.

I got this to work as intended within the Alpha class itself, but once I try the same outside of the Alpha class, in AlphaTest for example, it doesn't work as intended. Once I try that I'm hit with the following error:

`Error:(220, 23) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to models.Bravo`

It wants me to instantiate the instance as an Object like so:

`for(Object o: alphaInstance) {...}`

I could of course cast the object to Bravo. But that's not part of the assignment.

See code below to see what's going wrong. The problem can be found in `AlphaTest.java`.

`Alpha.java`

```java
class Alpha<E extends Bravo> implements Iterable<Bravo> {
    Bravo head;

    public Alpha(Bravo head) {
       this.head = head;
    }

    public void example() {
       for(Bravo b: this) {
          // This works, it's succesfully recognized as an instance of Bravo.
       }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Bravo> iterator() {
    return new BravoIterator(this.head);
    }

    private class BravoIterator implements Iterator<Bravo> {
       private Bravo currentBravo;

       public BravoIterator(Bravo head) {
          this.currentBravo = head;
       }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.currentBravo != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Wagon next() {
            Bravo data = this.currentBravo;
            this.currentBravo = this.currentBravo.getNextBravo();
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }
}
```

`AlphaTest.java`

```java
{...}

    @BeforeEach
    private void setup() {
        // Assume this is a doubly linked list
        Bravo bravo = new Bravo(...);
        

        instanceOfAlpha = new Alpha(bravo);
    }

    public T1_checkImplementationOfIterableInterface() {
       for(Bravo b: instanceOfAlpha) {  // <---------------------------------------------[This is the problem]
          // This does not work, it expects an instance of Object.
       }
    }

{...}
```

Comment: I think it does, I took a good look at AlphaTest.java and I realised that the prof. didn't actually make use of the generic in Alpha.java. Once I instantiated it with a generic of a class which extends Bravo it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You've mischaracterized the error.

What's happening is that `instanceOfAlpha` is an expression whose type ends up being `Alpha` - you've elided your definition of this variable, but it seems obvious enough, as you're creating the value for this variable with a raw type as well. `Alpha` would be a so-called **raw type** - a type that has type parameters, but where the parameters are missing.

The thing is, raw types are a tad odd: Once you go raw, **everything about it is raw**, even things that aren't using any of the generics you failed to specify. Thus, the `iterator()` method of your raw `Alpha` expression returns a raw `Iterator` (you'd think it returns an `Iterator<Bravo>`, but it does not). And therefore, iterating over it returns basic Objects. And therefore, your for loop is broken; `for (Object b : instanceOfAlpha){}` would compile; `for (Bravo b : instanceOfAlpha){}` won't.

The fix is generally that when the compiler throws warnings in your face that you shouldn't just go ¯_(ツ)_/¯ I don't know what those mean so I'll just be like the 3 monkeys and just wish that whatever I don't understand is hopefully utterly irrelevant.

It's not. The real fix is: Fix your generics so you don't get these warnings.

You haven't pasted enough code to tell you exactly what you need to do here; probably make `instanceOfAlpha` be declared as a `Alpha<?>`. More generally, your first paste (of your Alpha class) looks like you just don't get how generics works; most of the places that mention `Bravo` in that should have been using `E` instead. generics is a little tricky; perhaps you want to just opt out altogether. Get rid of the `<E extends Bravo>` part entirely, and then leave the rest pretty much as is, that would also fix things.

Comment: Gooed point about the monkeys :-D